# How to test and/or mock ref callback nodes and test .querySelector with Jest mocking + Enzyme shallow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Using Jest mocking and Enzyme shallow rendering, how would you test or mock the following?:

```
  onClick = () => {
    const inputNode = this.node.querySelector('input');
    inputNode.click();
  };
```

I tried:

```
it('calls button', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <Component />,
  );
  const wrapperInstance = wrapper.instance();
  const inputNode = document.createElement('input');
  inputNode.value = '';
  const node = document.createElement('div').appendChild(inputNode);
  wrapperInstance.node = node;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would mock the node.

```
it('calls button', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <Component />,
  );
  const wrapperInstance = wrapper.instance();
  const input = {value: 'someValue'}
  const node = {
    querySelector: (v) => v === 'input' ? input : null
  }
  wrapperInstance.node = node;
});
```